# remove cached (conda) environments in vscode for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Vscode freezes when I try to run `Python: Select Interpreted` 
The selection pane opens and lists my conda environments preceded by `(cached)`. 
However, I cannot select an interpreter and the vscode freezes completely.

Some of the environments shown are not even on my machine anymore. I suspect that deleting that cache might help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Within vscode, go to help > toggle developer tools > application > local storage. Filter local storage by interpreters. Cache seems to be stored there. Items can be deleted. Restart vscode.

Comment: Not seeing anything there.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting

I hope that helps.